# Vagrant port forwarding not working for nginx server

Tags: nginx, tcp, vagrant, gunicorn, portforwarding

I'm running an nginx->gunicorn->flask server in a Vagrant box on Ubuntu 20.04. I'm using supervisor to manage my gunicorn process and restart it, etc.

First I configure my Vagrantfile as follows:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
    config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.memory = "1024"
    end
end
```

When I go to 192.168.33.10 in my browser, I see the Flask app served properly by nginx on the VM.

But I want to have outside access to the app, so I change the Vagrantfile to forward port 8080 on my host machine to port 80 on the virtual machine:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
    config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
        vb.memory = "1024"
    end
end
```

From what I've seen online, this should allow me to go to localhost:8080 in my browser and see the Flask app. However, it doesn't work--I get "Unable to connect - Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost."

Here's my output of `ufw status` on the host

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080/tcp                   ALLOW       Anywhere                  
8080                       ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8080/tcp (v6)              ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
8080 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

and `iptables -L | grep policy` on the host (same on the VM):

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
```

and `ufw status` in the VM

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

If I try `curl localhost:8080` from the host machine:

```html
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

If I try `curl localhost` from the VM:

```html
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

When I do `sudo netstat -tlpn` on host machine:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41607           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2222          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      36868/VBoxHeadless  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:59951           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1260/rpc.mountd     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/init              
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      36868/VBoxHeadless  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:47859           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1260/rpc.mountd     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1079/systemd-resolv 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1282/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1129/cupsd          
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:34775           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1260/rpc.mountd     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::44203                :::*                    LISTEN      1260/rpc.mountd     
tcp6       0      0 :::45327                :::*                    LISTEN      -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/init              
tcp6       0      0 :::45141                :::*                    LISTEN      1260/rpc.mountd     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1282/sshd: /usr/sbi 
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      1129/cupsd          
tcp6       0      0 :::54619                :::*                    LISTEN      1260/rpc.mountd     
tcp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

And when I do `sudo netstat -tlpn` on the VM (I have nginx proxy_pass to 8000):

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1298/mysqld     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1420/nginx -g daemo
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1357/sshd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1625/master     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1420/nginx -g daemo
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1624/python3    
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1357/sshd       
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      1625/master
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How have you configured the virtualbox network adapter?

Comment: @Beel if I go into the VirtualBox manager GUI, click on the box in question->Settings->Network->Port Forwarding, I see the rule: {Name: tcp8080, Protocol: tcp, Host IP: , Host Port: 8080, Guest IP: , Guest Port: 80}. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: What's the type of network device?  NAT, Bridge, ?  I don't have access to a linux virtualbox instance so can't see what other settings might be ... but the "virtual NIC" used by virtualbox will have an impact on whether / how you can access the guest.

Comment: And just to add where I'm going (may not be helpful, but a thought) ... if it is a bridge, it will get a separate IP addy from your box (so you would access via that IP:8080 (or whatevs port). Also, be sure that your localhost is NOT using the target port - 8080 (since you don't have auto_correct set in vagrantfile).

Comment: and one more thought (sorry) ... the 301 responses are coming from somewhere.  Where?  Shutdown the VM ... do you still get those responses?  If so, you have a collision problem OR trying to access wrong URL ... ?

Comment: @Beel Thanks a lot for the help! The type of device is NAT, adapter type is Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540EM), Promiscuous mode is denied, and "Cable Connected" is checked. My localhost is using port 80. When I shut down the VM I don't get the 301 anymore, I just get connection refused. There's also a second virtual NIC adapter being used which is automatically created, this one is a Host-only adapter. By the way, when I run 'vagrant up' I see Forwarding ports...80 (guest) => 8080 (host) (adapter 1), which makes it look like everything is in order...also added netstat output to my question^

Comment: ok, so your vm is providing the 301?  then this does not seem to be a network issue ... does your guest's web server show the 301 in its logs?